# Objective C arc -- keeping a reference to a Class

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

I want to have an ivar of type Class, and to keep the pointer around after it is passed in.  But no matter what I do, arc will not let me do that.  For instance, if I declare

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) Class myClass;
```

the compiler decides that myClass should be unsafe_unretained.  And if I try this:

```
-(id) initWithClass: (Class) passedInClass {
   if ((self = [super init])) {
     self.myClass = passedInClass;
   }
   return self;
}
```

what happens is that even if the class is non-nil in the calling code, it is nil within the init method.

Short of turning off arc, is there any way to get around this?

EDIT: This question is just wrong.  It does work.  See the accepted answer.

Comment: Class is not compatible with ARC.  Some objc objects have custom memory management (i.e. they override retain release and dealloc), and therefore cannot be used with ARC.  I don't know if there is a list of them anywhere, but I'm pretty sure Class is one of them.  I don't know any solution so I won't post this as an answer.

Comment: @borrrden ARC handles Class pointers.  [clang Automatic Reference Counting, section 3 “Retainable object pointers”](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#objects): “There are three kinds of retainable object pointer types: … 
Objective-C object pointers (id, Class, NSFoo*, etc.) …”

Comment: @robmayoff Well how about that...I stand corrected >_<.  I looked for what I was thinking of, and I realize now that I was referring to how classes that override retain or release cannot be targets for WEAK references...so it was a different topic altogether.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Works as advertised with Xcode 4.3.2 targeting 10.7 and 5.1:

```
@interface MOYNObject : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) Class myClass;
@end

@implementation MOYNObject
@synthesize myClass;

- (id)initWithClass:(id)pClass
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil)
        self.myClass = pClass;
    assert(self.myClass);
    CFShow((__bridge const void*)self.myClass);
    return self;
}

@end

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        MOYNObject * o = [[MOYNObject alloc] initWithClass:[NSString class]];
        // ...
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Are you ahead of or behind 4.3.2?

Comment: I'm in 4.3.2; idk why yours works and mine does not.  I'll investigate.

Comment: You are correct.  I had an unrelated error and misinterpreted.